# how to get controls to overlap correctly in grid using zindex

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, z-index

So I'm trying to make my axis plane get drawn in the `ScrollViewer`, and then I want to come in and draw a list of signals over the space in which the axis was drawn, so that the signals go on top of the axis. I thought the correct thing was to use `ZIndex`, but I must be doing something wrong.

http://picpaste.com/signalgraph1-HSFHBYOG.JPG

Basically, it looks like the axis is of the size of `ScrollViewer` like I want, but then the `StackPanel` is being placed after the axis, instead of being placed 75 units down like I expect.

Why is this happening?  How can I get the behavior I want?

```
            <ScrollViewer 
                x:Name="signal_scrollviewer"
                Focusable="False"
                CanContentScroll="False">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="75" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <wpfExp:SignalGraphAxis Grid.ZIndex="1"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                        x:Name="signal_axis"
                                        Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_scrollviewer, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                        signal_graph_window_width="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                                        GraphHeight ="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        PenColor="{Binding ElementName=GraphColorPicker, Path=SelectedColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        PenWidth="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        MaxTimeValue="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=_SignalDataViewModel.MaxTimeValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                    />
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Grid.ZIndex="2" Grid.Row="1">
                  <ItemsPresenter />
                </StackPanel>
              </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Do not use a ZIndex with a Grid. Grid lays out it's children sequentially so if you just put your Axis control before the actual content in xaml it would be laying out the actual content "on top of" the axis control. oh that's for control's that are in the same Grid cell ofc

Comment: but what i want is for only part of the control to overlap. Is that possible?  I want the axis to start in row 0, but the portion in row 1 will get written on top of by the stackpanel in row 1

Comment: Yeh try setting the `Grid.RowSpan="2"` on your Axis element. Now in row 0 only Axis element exists however in Row 1 both Axis element and your `StackPanel` exist and with the Axis element occurring before `StackPanel` in xaml, it will be behind the `StackPanel` in row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viv is writing a good solution but you need to set `Grid.RowSpan="2"` to the `StackPanel` element and everything will work fine.

```
<ScrollViewer 
            x:Name="signal_scrollviewer"
            Focusable="False"
            CanContentScroll="False">
          <Grid>
            <wpfExp:SignalGraphAxis 
                                    x:Name="signal_axis"
                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_scrollviewer, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                    signal_graph_window_width="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                                    GraphHeight ="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    PenColor="{Binding ElementName=GraphColorPicker, Path=SelectedColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    PenWidth="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    MaxTimeValue="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=_SignalDataViewModel.MaxTimeValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Margin="0 75 0 0">
              <ItemsPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: But I want the stackpanel to start 75 down from the top. If I just set rowspan to 2, it starts at 0 and takes up all the space in the grid. It's the signalgraphaxis that i want to take 2 rows, so that's why i put rowspan=2, but i'm getting weird behavior where the stackpanel is in the middle of the page as shown in that picture i linked.

Comment: You need to put a margin of 75 then, I have updated the sample

Answer (score 0):

So when I changed this binding:

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_scrollviewer, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

to bind `Height` instead of `ActualHeight`, it appears to be working. I'm a little confused as to how the interactions could have caused what I saw though.